# Give border to menuitems in bootstrap nav

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In a boostrap 4 site, i am using the jquery mmenu plugin. I want to add some border to the menuitems, and for example, i attach a photo of what i want.

[Click here for the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW2cU.jpg)

On the photo, you can see some light brown or yellow border.

My generated menu html is this:

```
<div class="site_navigation">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars navbar_ikon"></i></span> </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-justified w-100 container mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a href="/kategoria/1/barabas-terko" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Barabás térkő</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/58/barabas-terko/barabas-antikolt-blokkelem">Barabás Antikolt blokkelem</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/55/barabas-terko/barabas-sed-hullam-terko">Barabás Séd hullám térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/44/barabas-terko/barabas-villany-kombi-terko">Barabás Villány Kombi térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/70/barabas-terko/barabas-zengo-terko">Barabás Zengő térkő</a> </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/kategoria/36/kerti-szegely" class="nav-link">Kerti szegély</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a href="/kategoria/10/terko-meret-szerint" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Térkő méret szerint</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/15/terko-meret-szerint/10x20-cm-terko">10x20 cm térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/18/terko-meret-szerint/20x13-3-cm-terko">20x13,3 cm térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/69/terko-meret-szerint/40-x-40-cm-terko">40 x 40 cm térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/68/terko-meret-szerint/60-x-40-cm-terko">60 x 40 cm térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/54/terko-meret-szerint/hullam-terko">Hullám térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/19/terko-meret-szerint/vegyes-meretu-kombi-terko">Vegyes méretű, kombi térkő</a> </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: use figure or caption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just use below** `css`.

```css
.site_navigation .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a{position:relative;}
.site_navigation .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a:before{content:'';position:absolute;right:0;top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%);height:10px;width:2px;background:#c49c61;}
.site_navigation .navbar-nav > li.nav-item:last-child > a:before{content:none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="site_navigation">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars navbar_ikon"></i></span> </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-justified w-100 container mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a href="/kategoria/1/barabas-terko" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Barabás térkő</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/58/barabas-terko/barabas-antikolt-blokkelem">Barabás Antikolt blokkelem</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/55/barabas-terko/barabas-sed-hullam-terko">Barabás Séd hullám térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/44/barabas-terko/barabas-villany-kombi-terko">Barabás Villány Kombi térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/70/barabas-terko/barabas-zengo-terko">Barabás Zengő térkő</a> </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/kategoria/36/kerti-szegely" class="nav-link">Kerti szegély</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a href="/kategoria/10/terko-meret-szerint" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Térkő méret szerint</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/15/terko-meret-szerint/10x20-cm-terko">10x20 cm térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/18/terko-meret-szerint/20x13-3-cm-terko">20x13,3 cm térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/69/terko-meret-szerint/40-x-40-cm-terko">40 x 40 cm térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/68/terko-meret-szerint/60-x-40-cm-terko">60 x 40 cm térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/54/terko-meret-szerint/hullam-terko">Hullám térkő</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/19/terko-meret-szerint/vegyes-meretu-kombi-terko">Vegyes méretű, kombi térkő</a> </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aligning and bordering the figure’s caption is easy

```html
<figure class="figure">
  <img src="..." class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
  <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right">A caption for the above image.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

See figures here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/figures/

See borders here : https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/utilities/borders/